# jquery ajax onsubmit form error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I hava a form that is given below

```
    <form name="frm_dcg" id="frm_dcg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" onsubmit="return validate_form();" >
            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="sign-in-htm">
-----------other codes-------
```

and the jquery function

```
function validate_form(){
    var run_name = $("#run_name").val();        
        $.ajax({
            url: "check_folder.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "run_name="+run_name,
            success: function (response) {
                if(response=="OK"){                     
                con = confirm("File already exists.. Do you want to replace existing file?");                               
                        if(con==true){
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            return false;
                        }
                } else{
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

The ajax is working fine, but the problem is form is submitting in any conditions. even if it is returning false. Please go through my code and let me know if there is any logical mistakes.

Comment: Ajax is a asynchronous call, your function will return before ajax call completes. add return false in your function just before block ends.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is an asynchronous function, meaning the `return false` you are calling happens way after the form is submitted.

Instead you have to add the return false at the end of the validate_form() function.

```
function validate_form(){
    var run_name = $("#run_name").val();        
    ...
   return false; // <-- before the ending curly brace
}
```

Note that the form should always return false. You can validate run_name use that to decide if you should do the ajax request or not.

```
function validate_form(){
    var run_name = $("#run_name").val(); 
    if (run_name.length > 5) { // just an example
        // do ajax request
    } else {
        // show invalid message
    }
    return false; // always false so the form doesn't submit.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the true/false result within the success closure. This won't get passed up to validate_form(). You also have a logic bug in the success handler that always returns true even if the response wasn't 'OK'.

You'll need to do something like:

```
function validate_form(){
    var form_success = false; // Always fail by default

    var run_name = $("#run_name").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "check_folder.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "run_name="+run_name,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "OK"){                     
                form_success = confirm("File already exists.. Do you want to replace existing file?");                               
            }

            form_success = false;
        }
    });

    return form_success;
}
```